# How to get search results older than 1 week on twitter

Tags: php, twitter, sttwitterapi

I am using twitter api by  https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php  to get search result from twitter. I am using until query string to get the past results

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';

$getfield ='?q=%40twitter&until=1-1-2017';
```

But this is not working, It giving me this result

[image]

I know twitter's `until` only gives result of last 7 days(maximum). But is their any trick to get the result of last 30 days?

Please help?